# How to make a alias to rsync?

Tags: linux, rsync, scp

I often use this command to sync remote and local.

```
rsync -xyz --foo=bar some_files user@remote.com:remote_dir
```

So I want to simplify this with an alias, like this:

```
up_remote () {
    local_files=${@:1:$((${#}-1))}  # treat argument[1:last-1] as local files
    remote_dir="${@[$#]}" # treat argument[last] as remote_dir
    echo $local_files
    echo $remote_dir
    rsync -xyz --foo=bar "$local_files" user@remote.com:"$remote_dir"
}
```

But if I pass three or more arguments it won't work:

```
up_remote local1 local2 remote_dir
```

When I debug this function with `set -x` I find that the function will generate `rsync` like this:

```
rsync -xyz --foo=bar 'local1 local2' user@remote.com:"$remote_dir"
```

Notice the single quotes(`'`) around `local1 local2`. If I remove these single quotes the `rsync` will work correctly, but I don't know how to do this.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Of course, it is a solution and will works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove the double quotes around `$local_files`:

```
up_remote () {
  local_files=${@:1:$((${#}-1))}
  remote_dir="${@:$#}"
  rsync -xyz --foo=bar $local_files a.b.com:"$remote_dir"
}
```

Note I also changed the way that `remote_dir` is picked, couldn't get your way to work in my version of bash.

Comment: Did you try to pass two or more arguments in `local_files`? Like this: `up_remote file1 file2 /tmp`
or 
     `up_remote file* /tmp`

Comment: Yes, both of those calling styles worked fine.  What version of bash are you using, and what output do you get with my function?

Comment: You're right. I used it in `zsh` before, it is my mistake. And it works in my `bash`. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Not really an answer but I did it with perl, and it works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @args = @ARGV;
my $files;

my $destination=pop(@args);

foreach(@args){
    $files.="'".$_."' ";
}

system("rsync -xyz --foo=bar $files user\@remote.com:$destination");
```

You can copy this script in your path or make an alias to it.

Comment: This will fail with filenames containing whitespace. Why not use something like String::ShellQuote?

Comment: You're right for the whitespace, a workaround is to add single quotes in the foreach (Edited in my answer)

Comment: Now it breaks if your filename has singlequotes. Same for destination. As I said, there is modules to do the escaping for you

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how I can do it properly with bash. Good luck ;)